# 8051 chip with USB

Tags: 8051

I need a 8051 chip with the following features.

1. SPI programmable. [ software supported on linux or windows]
2. With a internal configurable USB module.[with usb SIB]
3. 5V electrical configuration.
4. Chip should be mountable on the bred-board.

and I prefer this additional feature too.

- internal A/D unit.

My chip budget is 0$(Donate ME!) - 10$,
Could you suggest me a chip with a brand. My country welcome all brands
from any country[no RHoS].

--thanks in advance--

Comment: What's with the downvote? It should almost be a requirement on this site that a downvote for a question come from a frequent visitor or require moderation.

Comment: @AndrewKohlsmith So If I were to downvote, you would be ok with no explanation? We would be exactly in the same spot... I voted to close because it's a localized shopping question.

Comment: @w5vo usually the people who are the "regulars" have pretty good reasons for downvoting that most others see as obvious. Your downvote here must be the exception that proves the rule. :-) I didn't see this so much as a shopping question but rather asking for help in finding such a beast.

Comment: @AndrewKohlsmith I rarely downvote questions (didn't downvote this one), but I vote to close a lot. Incidentally, the closing dialog makes you justify your close vote.

Comment: My 1 minute with digikey implies that you can get everything except probably the programming requirement if you don't use a 8051, and no 8051 with USB comes in a DIP package.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the [Cypress FX2](http://www.cypress.com/?id=193) series of microcontrollers are 8051 based, and should take care of all of your requirements except for the ADC and breadboard, but [several](http://www.elrasoft.com/hsusbm.htm) [breakout](http://lea.hamradio.si/~s57uuu/uuusb/index.htm) [designs](http://www.knjn.com/FPGA-FX2.html) exist which might satisfy your breadboardable requirement, and it's got I2C which should make it easy to add an ADC (Analog Devices, Linear Tech, National Semiconductor and Maxim).